# Cover photo implementation

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making an app that allows the user to crop an image to form a cover photo for his/her profile.

I've finally able to set my content size of my scroll view properly, image can now scroll up and down perfectly fine. However, I'm now trying to implement zoom, but whenever I zoom, I am having the following 2 problems

- I can't scroll to the bottom of the image when zoomed in
- If I zoom back out, I can't scroll down anymore, the overlay and the image will remain the same as this screenshot.

[image: Current app]

The following is my code:

```
let scaleFactor = self.croppingOverlay.frame.width / photo.size.width

self.photoImageView.image = photo

self.photoImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.croppingOverlay.frame.origin.y, self.croppingOverlay.frame.width, photo.size.height * scaleFactor)
self.photoImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
self.photoImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
self.photoImageView.clipsToBounds = false
self.scrollView.addSubview(photoImageView)
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.croppingOverlay.frame.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height + (self.photoImageView.frame.size.height - self.croppingOverlay.frame.size.height))
self.scrollView.delegate = self

self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0

internal func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return self.photoImageView
}
```

I know I need a method func scrollViewDidZoom(scrollView: UIScrollView) but I've no idea about the content of the method
Any help would be GREATLY appreciated